# Rename the file names so that the appear in a specified sorted order

Tags: linux, shell, command-line

I have a list of files. They are currently appearing in this order :

```
Advance Topics in Graphs _ Lec 11 _ Discrete Mathematics _ Exam-lAN6B0Hvy7E.webm
Basics of Combinatorics _ Lec 12 _ Discrete Mathematics _ Exam-sBg13JNUQQ8.webm
Basics of Graph Theory _ Lec 6 _ Discrete Mathematics _ Exam-JqgdPH-PEIM.webm
Basics of Relations - 2 _ Lec 20 _ Discrete Mathematics _ Exam-CTo9pvl__5M.webm
Basics of Relations _ Lec 19 _ Discrete Mathematics _ Exam-4KTaggHRd54.webm
Basics of Sets _ Lec 18 _ Discrete Mathematics _ Exam-LE-Gt_PUdws.webm
```

I want to rename the files so that the file name has the following pattern(represented using regex for clarity) **Lec\s[0-9]?[0-9]?** that appears in the middle of the file names, appears in the beginning of the file name.(This is sorted order).

The final result will look like this:

```
Lec 6 Basics of Graph Theory _  _ Discrete Mathematics _ Exam-JqgdPH-PEIM.webm
Lec 11 Advance Topics in Graphs _  _ Discrete Mathematics _ Exam-lAN6B0Hvy7E.webm
Lec 12 Basics of Combinatorics _  _ Discrete Mathematics _ Exam-sBg13JNUQQ8.webm
Lec 18 Basics of Sets _  _ Discrete Mathematics _ Exam-LE-Gt_PUdws.webm
Lec 19 Basics of Relations _  _ Discrete Mathematics _ Exam-4KTaggHRd54.webm
Lec 20 Basics of Relations - 2 _  _ Discrete Mathematics _ Exam-CTo9pvl__5M.webm
```

Comment: for the future, you can change the output of [youtube-dl](https://ytdl-org.github.io/youtube-dl/index.html) to prefix the order in a playlist or sequence if that's how you came to the videos!

Comment: @ti7 i always do that. But i got this content from my friend. lol

Comment: See if you have [`rename`/ `prename`](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/perl/prename.1.en.html) available.

Comment: @Shawn Unable to locate the package(prename). I'll install rename.

Comment: @Shawn I don't know perl. Can you please frame the expression?

Comment: What is this -- my wish is your command?

Comment: @Roadowl That was a typo. I've updated the question.

Comment: There are multiple common incompatible utilities called `rename`. If you don't have the perl one I'm talking about, I'm not going to bother with an answer using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever I have a problem like this, I tend to write a 1-off script to do the work in Python, though you could replace it with whatever language of choice (ie. Perl, bash+awk, ..)

Primarily this is to ensure you know what the results will be before you really do the rename, which can be a destructive operation (throwing out identifiers, renaming all the input files to have the same name so only the last survives..)!

```py
import os
import re

def mapper(s):
    # adjust to taste, this just swaps the middle to the front
    prefix, index, postfix = re.match(r"^(.*) (?:Lec) (\d+) (.*)$", s).groups()
    return f"Lec {int(index):02} {prefix} {postfix}"  # pad index 2->02, etc.

mapping = {}  # start a new dictionary to store src->dest maps
for name_file in os.listdir():
    try:
        mapping[name_file] = mapper(name_file)
    except AttributeError:  # failed to match
        print(f"failed to match for {name_file}")

# display the change on separate lines
for src, dest in mapping.items():
    print(f"{src} -> {dest}")

# [return] or ^C to quit
input("continue?..")

# perform renames
for src, dest in mapping.items():
    os.rename(src, dest)
```

Comment: Thank you!
This is can be a generic answer too.

Answer (score 1):

Note: this requires `gawk` because of `gensub`

```
ls | awk '{a=gensub(/^(.*) (Lec [0-9]+) (.*)$/, "\\2 \\1\\3","1",$0);printf "mv \"%s\" \"%s\"\n",$0, a}' |  bash
```

Comment: the files are present in a directory. The names are not present in a text file.

Comment: Facing issues with gwak. Thank you for your efforts

Comment: Heh. You're welcome.  What trouble is `gawk` giving you?

Comment: E: Unable to locate package gwak. @tink

Comment: Oh.  Which distro are you using?

Comment: I'm using debian (ubuntu)

Comment: Did you try `apt install gawk` rather than `gwak`?  Ubuntu (Debian) by default uses `mawk`, but I haven't come across a single version of these that didn't have `gawk` in the repo ... :) @taurus05

Comment: i tried apt install gawk. Found a workaround on SO.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236158/discussion-between-tink-and-taurus05).

Answer (score 0):

Given:

```
ls -1 *.webm
Advance Topics in Graphs _ Lec 11 _ Discrete Mathematics _ Exam-lAN6B0Hvy7E.webm
Basics of Combinatorics _ Lec 12 _ Discrete Mathematics _ Exam-sBg13JNUQQ8.webm
Basics of Graph Theory _ Lec 6 _ Discrete Mathematics _ Exam-JqgdPH-PEIM.webm
Basics of Relations - 2 _ Lec 20 _ Discrete Mathematics _ Exam-CTo9pvl__5M.webm
Basics of Relations _ Lec 19 _ Discrete Mathematics _ Exam-4KTaggHRd54.webm
Basics of Sets _ Lec 18 _ Discrete Mathematics _ Exam-LE-Gt_PUdws.webm
```

I would just do a little one liner in Ruby:

```
ruby -e 'Dir.glob("*.webm"){
        |fn| File.rename(fn, fn.sub(/^([^_]*)_ ([^_]+? )_/,"\\2\\1_ _"))}'
```

Then:

```
ls -1 *.webm
Lec 11 Advance Topics in Graphs _ _ Discrete Mathematics _ Exam-lAN6B0Hvy7E.webm
Lec 12 Basics of Combinatorics _ _ Discrete Mathematics _ Exam-sBg13JNUQQ8.webm
Lec 18 Basics of Sets _ _ Discrete Mathematics _ Exam-LE-Gt_PUdws.webm
Lec 19 Basics of Relations _ _ Discrete Mathematics _ Exam-4KTaggHRd54.webm
Lec 20 Basics of Relations - 2 _ _ Discrete Mathematics _ Exam-CTo9pvl__5M.webm
Lec 6 Basics of Graph Theory _ _ Discrete Mathematics _ Exam-JqgdPH-PEIM.webm
```

BEWARE however that this (and all the other solutions here) will overwrite a file if the new name is the same as a previously generated name...